# how to select specific slide via VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an Excel with Macro which should:
toggle to active PPT
select slide "X" and delete graphs
Go to Tab "X" in excel
grab new Graph
Paste onto the "X" slide
repeat 5 times

here is the code I've compiled so far:

```
Dim PPT As Object
Dim rng As Object
Dim rng1 As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim ActivePresentation As Object


'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 6")
Set rng1 = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 7")
Set rng2 = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 8")

Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

With PPT
.Visible = True
.WindowState = 1
.Activate
End With
'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")


Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add *this should not say add as it adds a slide,but no luck with any other commands*
' PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) *this should not say add as it adds a slide,but no luck with any other commands*
'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 20
      myShape.Top = 152

rng1.Copy
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
  myShape.Left = 486
      myShape.Top = 152

      Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(2, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

     etc..


End Sub
```

this creates a new PPT and add slides to the new ppt, have tried a numerous helps and web pages but unfortunately was not able to find a piece of code which would tackle this problem. Would be much appreciated if you could advise or point me to the correct help or tutorial which would be possible to solve this issue with.

Comment: Hello & welcome to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to find out how a Q & A site differs from a standard forum. TL;DR - this isn't a code writing service. Post your code and indicate where the specific error is and someone will help you fix it, but we're not going to do it for you.

Comment: `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation`? And then what slide do you want to select??

Comment: slide 2 to be selected, than slide 3 until slide 5

Answer (score 0):

code is based on the following assumptions from your statement

1. Already have a presentation open
2. want to copy two or three charts from each sheets, starting from Sheets(2) to Sheets(5) to slides 2 to 5 respectively as shown below.

[image]
Code may be modified to your requirement

```
Sub AddtoOpenPPT()
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim Fname As String
Dim sld As Long, i As Long, ObjNo As Long
Dim Rng(0 To 9)  As Object

Set Rng(0) = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 6")
Set Rng(1) = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 7")
Set Rng(2) = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 8")
Set Rng(3) = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 5")
Set Rng(4) = Sheet1.Range("b4:j14")
Set Rng(5) = Sheet1.Range("A4:l4", "A15:j19")
Set Rng(6) = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 13")
Set Rng(7) = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 15")
Set Rng(8) = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 17")
Set Rng(9) = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 19")


Set PPT = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
Set myPresentation = PPT.ActivePresentation
    ObjNo = 0
    For sld = 2 To 5
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(sld)

            For i = mySlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            mySlide.Shapes(i).Delete
            Next

            For i = 1 To 3
            Rng(ObjNo).Copy
            mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
            Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            myShape.Left = IIf(i Mod 2 = 1, 20, 486)
            myShape.Top = IIf(i < 3, 50, 200)
            ObjNo = ObjNo + 1
            If ObjNo > UBound(Rng) Then Exit For
            Next
    If ObjNo > UBound(Rng) Then Exit For
    Next sld
    End Sub
```

Comment: You please Add reference to **Microsoft PowerPoint XX Object library** in VBA project window's Tools->Reference. Please Feedback.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, however it does not pass
I get compile error: user defined type not defined for line 2 &3

Comment: Have you added reference to Microsoft PowerPoint ... Object library ?

Comment: all fine up to this part
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sld).ChartObjects(i).Copy

Comment: This means You don't have 3 charts in of the 4 slides Ii.e. slides 2 to 5). Please give details (names and numbers) of charts (to be copied) existing in the each of the sheets 2 to  5.

Comment: Set rng = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 6")

Set rng1 = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 7")

Set rng2 = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 8")
Set rng3 = Sheet3.ChartObjects("Chart 5")
Set rng4 = Sheet1.Range("b4:j14")
Set rng5 = Sheet1.Range("A4:l4:A15:j19")
Set rng6 = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 13")
Set rng7 = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 15")
Set rng8 = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 17")
Set rng9 = Sheet4.ChartObjects("Chart 19")